# Make rows unchangeable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rows

Just a simple question really .. Imagine that you have a table with data and you need to update something in it once a month and then save it. After that your DB should forbid ANY additional changes to the affected rows but keep them. Presumably forever and without deleting those rows.

How would I implement this in a good way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more solution: [read only filegroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx):

```
ALTER DATABASE Test
MODIFY FILEGROUP [FG2] READ_ONLY;
```

Example:

```
CREATE DATABASE Test;
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test ADD FILEGROUP FG2
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test ADD FILE 
(
    NAME = 'SecondFile',
    FILENAME = 'D:\BD\SecondFile.ndf'
) TO FILEGROUP FG2;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable2 (Col1 INT) ON FG2;
INSERT dbo.MyTable2 VALUES (11);
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test
MODIFY FILEGROUP [FG2] READ_ONLY;
GO
INSERT dbo.MyTable2 VALUES (22);
GO
/*
Msg 652, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The index "" for table "dbo.MyTable2" (RowsetId 72057594060210176) resides on a read-only filegroup ("FG2"), which cannot be modified.
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

revoke update/insert/delete on the table from all normal users

Answer (score 0):

Implementing complex constraints like this can be done with a `TRIGGER`. Use with caution though, because they can turn into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Triggers are never a good idea... There is no way to know which other triggers might be 'triggered'.

Comment: @woony The answer already contains a disclaimer that they should be used with caution. I've personally never used them in a production situation, but to say they are *never* a good idea seems silly to me. You cannot oversee all possible scenarios, and the functionality is there.

Answer (score 0):

Use "view" as table's portion except that row you mention to protect. Maybe a dynamic view. So people cannot change the row they cannot see.